# Azure : I don't see all my Trace log

Tags: c#, .net, logging, azure, azure-diagnostics

I work with VisualStudio2010 and emulators tools (June 2012).
I create a new Work Role Project.

In the *WorkerRole.cs* file :

```cs
public class WorkerRole : RoleEntryPoint
{
    public override void Run()
    {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Begin loop at " + DateTime.Now);
        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Trace.TraceInformation("I'm in a loop (" + i++ + ") at " + DateTime.Now + ".");
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
        }
    }

    private void InitLogs()
    {
        DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
        config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Verbose;
        config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

        DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);
        Trace.TraceInformation("Start at " + DateTime.Now);
    }

    public override bool OnStart()
    {
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 12;
        InitLogs();
        return base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

In my *settings* :

```cs
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString = UseDevelopmentStorage=true
```

In *app.config* :

```xml
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
        <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
                name="AzureDiagnostics">
                <filter type="" />
            </add>
        </listeners>
    </trace>
</system.diagnostics>
```

When I Start Debugging (F5) in local, I can see this in the *Windows Azure Compute Emulator* :

```
[fabric] Role Instance: deployment16(275).WindowsAzureProject2.WorkerRole1.0
[fabric] Role state Started
[Diagnostics]: UpdateState(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration, )
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   OnStart()
[Diagnostics]: Acquired mutex
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor
[Diagnostics] Information: c:\users\benjamin.lux\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsAzureProject2\WindowsAzureProject2\csx\Debug\roles\WorkerRole1\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile "C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown-54bc885b045e40ecaf8474c810199ab5 -InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-54bc885b045e40ecaf8474c810199ab5 -parent 7656 -events
[Diagnostics]: UpdateState(Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorStartupInfo, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration, )
[Diagnostics]: Mutex already taken
[Diagnostics]: Creating config channel client
[Diagnostics]: Attempting to connect to server...
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:17:40.111Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6920
[MonAgentHost] Error:     4636
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SelfMonitoring
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\agent\dll\selfmon.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     MASelfMon::GetProcCntrs
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1421
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffffc0000bb8
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     PdhAddCounter(\Process(MonAgentHost#0)\ID Process) failed
[Diagnostics]: Creating config channel server
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-54bc885b045e40ecaf8474c810199ab5 is signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-54bc885b045e40ecaf8474c810199ab5 after the agent is initialized.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 7656 exits.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling
[Diagnostics]: Connection sucessful, sending config
[WaWorkerHost.exe] Start at 09/07/2012 10:17:40
[runtime] Role entrypoint . COMPLETED OnStart()
[Diagnostics]: Config request received
[Diagnostics]: Signalling process restart on event = WADDM-ShutDown-54bc885b045e40ecaf8474c810199ab5
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:17:40.662Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     3
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6920
[MonAgentHost] Error:     4636
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SelfMonitoring
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\agent\dll\selfmon.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     MASelfMon::StartTerminationCountdown
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1088
[MonAgentHost] Error:     10011
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Not starting termination thread inside a client hosted monitoring agent
[MonAgentHost] Output: Exiting the monitoring agent 6920 after the shutdown event was signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Stopped
[Diagnostics] Information: Diagnostic process exited with code: 0
[runtime] Role entrypoint . CALLING   Run()
[WaWorkerHost.exe] Begin loop at 09/07/2012 10:17:40
[WaWorkerHost.exe] I'm in a loop (0) at 09/07/2012 10:17:40.
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor
[Diagnostics] Information: c:\users\benjamin.lux\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsAzureProject2\WindowsAzureProject2\csx\Debug\roles\WorkerRole1\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile "C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown-5548c4bc522e4f858d6ab6df287747cf -InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-5548c4bc522e4f858d6ab6df287747cf -parent 7656 -events
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:17:42.930Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6260
[MonAgentHost] Error:     5472
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SelfMonitoring
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\agent\dll\selfmon.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     MASelfMon::GetProcCntrs
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1421
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffffc0000bb8
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     PdhAddCounter(\Process(MonAgentHost#0)\ID Process) failed
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-5548c4bc522e4f858d6ab6df287747cf is signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-5548c4bc522e4f858d6ab6df287747cf after the agent is initialized.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 7656 exits.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling
[WaWorkerHost.exe] I'm in a loop (1) at 09/07/2012 10:17:55.
[WaWorkerHost.exe] I'm in a loop (2) at 09/07/2012 10:18:10.
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:18:15.202Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6260
[MonAgentHost] Error:     5412
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\netutils.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     OpenHttpSession
[MonAgentHost] Error:     749
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2f94
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:18:22.313Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6260
[MonAgentHost] Error:     7912
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\netutils.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     OpenHttpSession
[MonAgentHost] Error:     749
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2f94
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:18:24.578Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6260
[MonAgentHost] Error:     7912
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\netutils.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     OpenHttpSession
[MonAgentHost] Error:     749
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2f94
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
[WaWorkerHost.exe] I'm in a loop (3) at 09/07/2012 10:18:25.
[Diagnostics]: Checking for configuration updates 09/07/2012 10:18:40.
[WaWorkerHost.exe] I'm in a loop (4) at 09/07/2012 10:18:40.
[Diagnostics]: Signalling process restart on event = WADDM-ShutDown-5548c4bc522e4f858d6ab6df287747cf
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:18:40.731Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     3
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6260
[MonAgentHost] Error:     5472
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SelfMonitoring
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\agent\dll\selfmon.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     MASelfMon::StartTerminationCountdown
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1088
[MonAgentHost] Error:     10011
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     Not starting termination thread inside a client hosted monitoring agent
[MonAgentHost] Output: Exiting the monitoring agent 6260 after the shutdown event was signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Stopped
[Diagnostics] Information: Diagnostic process exited with code: 0
[Diagnostics] Information: C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor
[Diagnostics] Information: c:\users\benjamin.lux\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\WindowsAzureProject2\WindowsAzureProject2\csx\Debug\roles\WorkerRole1\diagnostics\x64\monitor\MonAgentHost.exe -LocalPath "C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor" -StaticConfigFile "C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\mastaticconfig.xml" -ConfigFile "C:\Users\benjamin.lux\AppData\Local\dftmp\Resources\0f8904a1-352a-4726-a1fc-17fb8d128797\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\Configuration\maconfig.xml" -ShutDownEvent WADDM-ShutDown-88b62f24f2154dbabb56a138a624ff8a -InitializedEvent WADM-StartUp-88b62f24f2154dbabb56a138a624ff8a -parent 7656 -events
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:18:42.920Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6068
[MonAgentHost] Error:     7820
[MonAgentHost] Error:     SelfMonitoring
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\agent\dll\selfmon.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     MASelfMon::GetProcCntrs
[MonAgentHost] Error:     1421
[MonAgentHost] Error:     ffffffffc0000bb8
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     PdhAddCounter(\Process(MonAgentHost#0)\ID Process) failed
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when WADDM-ShutDown-88b62f24f2154dbabb56a138a624ff8a is signaled.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Will signal WADM-StartUp-88b62f24f2154dbabb56a138a624ff8a after the agent is initialized.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Registered as an event consumer.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Agent will exit when parent process 7656 exits.
[MonAgentHost] Output: Monitoring Agent Started
[Diagnostics]: Starting configuration channel polling
[WaWorkerHost.exe] I'm in a loop (5) at 09/07/2012 10:18:55.
[WaWorkerHost.exe] I'm in a loop (6) at 09/07/2012 10:19:10.
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:19:15.198Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6068
[MonAgentHost] Error:     612
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\netutils.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     OpenHttpSession
[MonAgentHost] Error:     749
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2f94
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:19:22.313Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6068
[MonAgentHost] Error:     7748
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\netutils.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     OpenHttpSession
[MonAgentHost] Error:     749
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2f94
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
[MonAgentHost] Error: MA EVENT: 2012-07-09T08:19:24.577Z
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2
[MonAgentHost] Error:     6068
[MonAgentHost] Error:     7748
[MonAgentHost] Error:     NetTransport
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     x:\btsdx\215\services\monitoring\shared\nettransport\src\netutils.cpp
[MonAgentHost] Error:     OpenHttpSession
[MonAgentHost] Error:     749
[MonAgentHost] Error:     0
[MonAgentHost] Error:     2f94
[MonAgentHost] Error:     
[MonAgentHost] Error:     WinHttpGetProxyForUrl(http://127.0.0.1) failed ERROR_WINHTTP_AUTODETECTION_FAILED (12180)
[WaWorkerHost.exe] I'm in a loop (7) at 09/07/2012 10:19:25.
[WaWorkerHost.exe] I'm in a loop (8) at 09/07/2012 10:19:40.
```

So I can see Trace message 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and 8.
But when I take a look to my "WADLogsTable" I have just message : Start, 1, 2, 3 and 4,  **no Begin, number 0 and 5, 6, 7 and 8**.

Tow main questions : 
Where are they ?
What it happens if I stop an instance betwen tow "transfer period" of logging ? 
In this case my last logs are save or I have to force the upload by use the *DeploymentDiagnosticManager* Class ?

Second question is because maybe the 4 lasts messages aren't a problem.

For Information errors in the *Windows Azure Compute Emulator* aren't importants : [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/01/20/winhttpgetproxyforurl-failed-error-winhttp-autodetection-failed-12180-error-message-in-windows-azure-infrastructure-log.aspx)

Edit 09/07/2012 : clarify the situation.

**Edit** 16/07/2012 : If someone could create a new worker role project and add the code above then press F5. I want know if it is a personal deal or a problem of emulator (or other).

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience you must use SetCurrentConfiguration before starting your diagnostics monitor otherwise trace logs are not transferred to WadLogsTable. This will use the current log transfer time to move the logs. 
Can you also add the time Tick will your logs to see when the were created?

Comment: He said he sees data in the WadLogsTable.  It is incomplete (and not on beginning or end of data where timing should be an issue).  I have not seen this before...

Comment: I agree. However my hunch is that the scheduled time is not changed correctly and that why the logs transferred are not sync with time. I have seen in past similar problem that's why I suggested to be sure that scheduled transfer time is fixed 60 sec and with tick count it can be measured if there is any issue with it. This is just to be sure that all is done correctly.

Comment: I've edited my post. I don't understand why I should use SetCurrentConfiguration ? Because it don't look easy to use. But I will look this in the afternoon.